# Angular to refresh array after updating fields through modal instance

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

To edit object details I use ui bootstrap modal directive. I use same controller to add new entity or edit already existing one. With my current code when I add a new object, it gets pushed to the array. Now I have a problem when updating an existing object. My current code also pushes the updated object to the array, but not to the database and shows me duplicate of the old record and the new one in array. After refresh the old one disappears of course because the controller queries the actual array again.

```
$scope.openSaleDlg = function (saleId) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        backdrop: 'static',
        templateUrl: '/sales/detail.html',
        controller: 'SaleDetailCtrl',
        scope: $scope,
        resolve: {
            saleId: function () {
                return saleId;
            }
        }
    });

modalInstance.result.then(
    function (sale) {
        $scope.sales.push(sale)
    }
);
```

};

I could have the .then do `$scope.sales = Sale.query();` on success, but maybe there's a better way to just update the object in the list by not querying the database again?

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the element in the list by id and [extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) it if it exists, rather than pushing it to the array?

Comment: An example would be appreciated. Not very familiar with this method.

Answer (score 1):

You could do just as you suggest and update the object in the list if it exists, rather than pushing it.  Angular will pick up the change and re-render.

Something like:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (sale) {
  var saleToUpdate = $scope.sales.find(function (existingSale) {
    return existingSale.id == sale.id;
  });

  if (saleToUpdate) {
    angular.extend(saleToUpdate, sale);
  } else {
    $scope.sales.push(sale);
  }
});
```

Note that `Array#find` would require a polyfill (or you could use a different method to search the array).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to save the 'sale' index, like that:

```
 $scope.openSaleDlg = function (sale) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        backdrop: 'static',
        templateUrl: '/sales/detail.html',
        controller: 'SaleDetailCtrl',
        scope: $scope,
        resolve: {
            saleId: function () {
                return sale.Id;
            }
        }
    });
    $scope.saleIndex = $scope.sales.indexOf(sale)
    modalInstance.result.then(
        function (sale) {
    if($scope.saleIndex >-1){
      $scope.sales[$scope.saleIndex] = sale;
    }
    else{
        $scope.sales.push(sale)
    }

    }
);
```